# How to change the width of a line in a tabularx in a survey?

Tags: tabularx

I copied this code from another question in this forum.
However, how can I change the width of this specific line (cf. %this line -> how to change the width?) to make it automatically adjust to the text within this line? Unfortunately, the text is "overlapping".

Thanks,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5em}}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % redefine 'X' to use 'm'

\begin{document}

\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}{|X|S|S|S|S|S|X|}
  \hline
  QUESTION? & $ BEISPIEL1 $ & $ BEISPIEL2 $ & $ BEISPIEL3 $ & $ BEISPIEL4 $ & $++$ &\\
  \hline %this line -> how to change width?
  is complicated to use & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & is not complicated to use\\
  \hline
bietet nicht alle Funktionen um die anfallenden Aufgaben effizient zu bewältigen  & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & bietet alle Funktionen, um die anfallenden Aufgaben effizient zu bewältigen
\end{tabularx}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please always post the example as a complete docuemnt that shows the issue. Your question is unclear. In the title you ask to change the width of a **column** of the table, but the example looks like asking to change the width of an `\hline`

Comment: for the lines, use `booktabs` package and `\toprule` `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`   (or see the package documentation for finer control)

Comment: What's the reason for `\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}`? Why not simply use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` instead?

Comment: What does "automatically adjust to the text" refer to? Probably a sketch of the desired output yould help clarify.

Comment: The picture I uploaded (https://i.stack.imgur.com/atMH2.png) shows that the words (Beispiel 1, Beipsiel 2, etc.) in the top row are too close to each other. I don't know how to solve that. -> documenclass is article (\documentclass{article}). don't know why it does not show.

Comment: Well, you explicitly used `S` type columns which are only `1.2em` wide. You could try with `c` instead. However, this will leave just very little room for the first and last column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % redefine 'X' to use 'm'

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|*{5}{>{\centering}m{1.5em}}|L|}
  \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{QUESTION?}           
    & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{BEISPIEL}  
        &                           \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & $++$ &  \\
  \Xhline{1pt} %this line -> how to change width?
is complicated to use 
    & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ 
        & is not complicated to use\\
  \hline
bietet nicht alle Funktionen um die anfallenden Aufgaben effizient zu bewältigen  
    & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ 
        & bietet alle Funktionen, um die anfallenden Aufgaben effizient zu bewältigen
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

*Note:*

- Use of column tape symbolw which is defined with some package, in your case by `siunitx` is not good idea
- for thicker `\hline` is used `Xhline{<width}` defined in the `makecell` package
- please always provide complete MWE (in yours is missed `\documentclas{...}`